# how can I retrive the data ,when app force closes from ram in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using shared preferences to store data.whenever I close and opens the app, it will read the shared prefs value and retain the same state.I am getting correctly when I press back.But when I remove an app from memory or force close, shared preference get cleared.I am getting the null value when I reopened the app.how to retrieve values even when I removes the app from memory.`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Conveyer=(SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.tubelight);
        fan=(SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.Fan);
        ac=(SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.AC);
        motor=(SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.Motor);

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
         editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        A=sharedPreferences.getString("Conveyer","0");
        B=sharedPreferences.getString("fan","0");
        C=sharedPreferences.getString("ac","0");
        D=sharedPreferences.getString("motor","0");

        new fetchingjson().execute();
        if(A=="1"){
            Conveyer.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            Conveyer.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(B=="1"){
            fan.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            fan.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(C=="1"){
            ac.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            ac.setChecked(false);
        }

        if(D=="1"){
            motor.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            motor.setChecked(false);
        }




        Conveyer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean ischecked) {
                if(ischecked){
                    A="1";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "conveyer is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    A="0";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "conveyer is turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new fetchingjson().execute();

            }
        });
        fan.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean ischecked) {
                if(ischecked){
                    B="1";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fan is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    B="0";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fan is turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new fetchingjson().execute();
            }
        });
        ac.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean ischecked) {
                if(ischecked){
                    C="1";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "AC is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    C="0";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "AC is turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new fetchingjson().execute();
            }
        });
        motor.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean ischecked) {
                if(ischecked){
                   D="1";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    D="0";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motor is turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new fetchingjson().execute();
            }
        });

    }




    private class fetchingjson extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    String url = "http://youwalks.com/get.php?a="+A+"&b="+B+"&c="+C+"&d="+D;

    ProgressDialog dialogProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    AndroidHttpClient mmClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
    private String response="";
        private  String jstr;
        char phase[];

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            response = mmClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        jstr=""+response;


        if(jstr.equals(null))
        Log.i("url", "" + url);
        Log.i("routes", "" + response);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialogProgress.setCancelable(true);
        dialogProgress.setMessage("Please wait..");
        dialogProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialogProgress.show();
    }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            dialogProgress.dismiss();
            Log.i("responseeer",""+A);
        }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(fan.isChecked()){
            editor.putString("fan", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editor","true");
        }
        else{
            editor.putString("fan", "0");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editor","false");
        }
        if(motor.isChecked()){
            editor.putString("motor", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","true");
        }
        else{
            editor.putString("motor", "0");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","false");
        }
        if(Conveyer.isChecked()){
            editor.putString("Conveyer", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","true");
        }
        else{
            editor.putString("Conveyer", "0");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","false");
        }if(ac.isChecked()){
            editor.putString("ac", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","true");
        }
        else{
            editor.putString("ac", "0");
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("editorac","false");
        }


    }
```

`

Comment: Shared preferences and databases are affiliated with app they are created in, if you delete the app obviously the data gets deleted as well. Try saving data in some file in mobile rather than in shared preference or database.

Comment: @BhaveshMisri thank you.saving in mobile means ,i need to create new folder and save there?isn,t it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have to create a new folder and put all your data in it and then you can retrieve data from that location later on.